PostgreSQL dynamic pivot
just trying my luck here as I've thought I'd searched enough for an answer but is a bit out of luck.
I have this query,
SELECT child_name,
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2025' THEN _value END) AS "X.2025",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2026' THEN _value END) AS "X.2026",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2027' THEN _value END) AS "X.2027",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2028' THEN _value END) AS "X.2028",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2029' THEN _value END) AS "X.2029",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2030' THEN _value END) AS "X.2030",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2031' THEN _value END) AS "X.2031",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2032' THEN _value END) AS "X.2032",
    SUM(CASE WHEN date_string = '2033' THEN _value END) AS "X.2033"
FROM prod."tbl.SystemRegions"
WHERE ("model_name" = model_name)
AND (property_name = 'Load')
GROUP BY child_name
ORDER BY child_name;`

is there a way to make the pivot dynamic, because different "model_name"s will have different start and end date_string?
What I've tried is this on a test table,
CREATE TABLE test_stuff_here."ProductSales" (
    Productname varchar(50),
    year_value text,
    Sales int
);

INSERT INTO test_stuff_here."ProductSales" VALUES
    ('A','2017',100),
    ('A','2018',150),
    ('A','2019',300),
    ('A','2020',500),
    ('A','2021',450),
    ('A','2022',675),
    ('B','2018',900),
    ('B','2019',1120),
    ('B','2020',750),
    ('B','2021',1500),
    ('B','2022',1980);

    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_stuff_here.pivot_dynamic(IN table_name text) RETURNS void AS $$
    DECLARE
    col_names TEXT;
    dynamic_sql TEXT;
    BEGIN
    SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT year_value, ', ') INTO col_names
    FROM test_stuff_here."ProductSales";

        dynamic_sql := format('
        SELECT productname, ' || col_names || '
        FROM prod.crosstab(
             SELECT productname, year_value, sales FROM test_stuff_here.%I,

             ) AS ct (productname varchar, ' || col_names || ' text)', table_name
         );

     EXECUTE dynamic_sql;

END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

And I'm getting this error
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"
LINE 4: SELECT productname, year_value, sales FROM test\_...
        ^
QUERY:  
SELECT productname, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022
FROM prod.crosstab(
SELECT productname, year_value, sales FROM test_stuff_here."ProductSales",

    ) AS ct (productname varchar, 2017, 2018, 2019, 2020, 2021, 2022 text)

CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function test_stuff_here.pivot_dynamic(text) line 17 at EXECUTE

SQL state: 42601


No, because SQL function calls need to know the output names and types at call time. It's easier to pivot dynamically in your app, not the db, or you'll have to use a two-step call where the first call runs the operation and dumps the dynamic structure somewhere, and the second step reads that. That way the first one has a constant return structure and the pivoted data is just a side-effect. And that dynamic structure is already established and known at the time of the 2nd call.

Related threads: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

The error you're getting is because crosstab() wants a text with the query in it, and you didn't wrap the query in quotes, making it instead a multi-column subquery that ends with an unmatched comma. It's best if you switch to named dollar quotes if you need to nest quoted values (your function body is already one layer of quoting, then format() has its own, and in it, crosstab() also wants a quoted text value).


is there a way to make the pivot dynamic, because different "model_name"s will have different start and end date_string?

No, not directly. The output columns, types and names need to be known at call time and in your case the names must change and their number may vary.
To side-step the limitation, you need a 2-step process:

A routine establishes the target output structure and populates it, as a side effect, without returning it directly to the caller. Instead, it can just communicate where it's saved.
The caller reads the output saved as the side-effect of the routine they just called.

If later in development you wanted to make that void-returning function somehow return the structure directly, that wouldn't work, but you were close to finishing the first step of the 2-step thing:
demo at db<>fiddle
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_stuff_here.pivot_dynamic(
   IN input_table_schema text
  ,IN input_table_name text
  ,IN output_table_schema text default 'test_stuff_here'
  ,IN output_table_name text default 'pivot_dynamic_out') 
RETURNS void AS $f$
DECLARE col_names TEXT;
        col_names_typed TEXT;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE format(
     $g$SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT '"'||year_value||'"', ', ') 
              ,STRING_AGG(DISTINCT '"'||year_value||'" int', ', ')
        FROM %1$I.%2$I
     $g$, input_table_schema
        , input_table_name)
  INTO  col_names
      , col_names_typed;
  EXECUTE format(
     $g$DROP TABLE IF EXISTS %1$I.%2$I;
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %1$I.%2$I AS
        SELECT productname, %3$s
        FROM crosstab(
           $h$SELECT productname, year_value, sales FROM %4$I.%5$I
           $h$) AS ct (productname varchar, %6$s)
     $g$, output_table_schema
        , output_table_name
        , col_names
        , input_table_schema
        , input_table_name
        , col_names_typed);
END $f$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

The two steps:
select test_stuff_here.pivot_dynamic('test_stuff_here','ProductSales');
select * from test_stuff_here.pivot_dynamic_out;




productname
2017
2018
2019
2020
2021
2022




A
100
150
300
500
450
675


B
900
1120
750
1500
1980
null




As per the comment, crosstab() expects a text argument with the query in it, and you didn't wrap the query in quotes, making it instead a multi-column subquery.
The query you were giving to crosstab() had a trailing comma for some reason.
col_names can't be re-used in AS after the crosstab() call, because it's missing the type specification after each column name.
You'll be way more comfortable using named dollar quotes instead of the single quotes, if you're nesting quoted strings. Your function body is already one layer of quoting, then format() has its own, then inside that format() the crosstab() call also wants a quoted text value.


thanks @Zegarek! Confirming that this works on my case!
